# Improve Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
CPLUS=g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3
LIBS = -lm -lopenblas -llapacke -lvl
HEADERS = -I./vlfeat-0.9.21

all: classification_scheme

classification_scheme: ./output/main.o ./output/trainpredict.o ./output/svm.o ./output/general_utilities.o ./output/postprocess.o ./output/preprocess.o \
./output/load_data.o ./output/data_structures.o ./output/slic.o ./output/texture_pipelines.o ./output/kmeans.o ./output/vlad.o  ./output/bow.o  ./output/gmm.o \
./output/fishervectors.o  ./output/sift.o ./output/dsift.o
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -o classification_scheme ./output/trainpredict.o ./output/texture_pipelines.o ./output/slic.o ./output/svm.o ./output/general_utilities.o \
./output/postprocess.o ./output/preprocess.o ./output/load_data.o ./output/data_structures.o ./output/kmeans.o ./output/vlad.o ./output/bow.o  ./output/gmm.o \
./output/fishervectors.o ./output/sift.o ./output/dsift.o ./output/main.o $(LIBS)

./output/main.o: main.c ./output/texture_pipelines.o ./output/preprocess.o
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c -o ./output/main.o main.c
./output/trainpredict.o: ./svm/trainpredict.h ./svm/trainpredict.c ./output/svm.o
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c -o ./output/trainpredict.o ./svm/trainpredict.c
./output/svm.o: ./svm/svm.cpp ./svm/svm.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -o ./output/svm.o -c ./svm/svm.cpp
./output/load_data.o: ./utility/load_data.c ./utility/load_data.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -c ./utility/load_data.c -o ./output/load_data.o
./output/data_structures.o: ./utility/data_structures.c ./utility/data_structures.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -c ./utility/data_structures.c -o ./output/data_structures.o
./output/preprocess.o: ./utility/preprocess.c ./utility/preprocess.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c ./utility/preprocess.c -o ./output/preprocess.o
./output/postprocess.o: ./utility/postprocess.c ./utility/postprocess.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -c ./utility/postprocess.c -o ./output/postprocess.o
./output/general_utilities.o: ./utility/general_utilities.c ./utility/general_utilities.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -c ./utility/general_utilities.c -o ./output/general_utilities.o
./output/slic.o: ./texture/slic.cpp ./texture/slic.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -c ./texture/slic.cpp -o ./output/slic.o
./output/texture_pipelines.o: ./texture/texture_pipelines.cpp ./texture/texture_pipelines.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c ./texture/texture_pipelines.cpp -o ./output/texture_pipelines.o
./output/kmeans.o: ./texture/kmeans.cpp ./texture/kmeans.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -c ./texture/kmeans.cpp -o ./output/kmeans.o
./output/vlad.o: ./texture/vlad.cpp ./texture/vlad.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -c ./texture/vlad.cpp -o ./output/vlad.o
./output/bow.o: ./texture/bow.cpp ./texture/bow.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) -c ./texture/bow.cpp -o ./output/bow.o
./output/gmm.o: ./texture/gmm.cpp ./texture/gmm.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c ./texture/gmm.cpp -o ./output/gmm.o
./output/fishervectors.o: ./texture/fishervectors.cpp ./texture/fishervectors.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c ./texture/fishervectors.cpp -o ./output/fishervectors.o
./output/sift.o: ./texture/sift.cpp ./texture/sift.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c ./texture/sift.cpp -o ./output/sift.o
./output/dsift.o: ./texture/dsift.cpp ./texture/dsift.h
    $(CPLUS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c ./texture/dsift.cpp -o ./output/dsift.o
clean:
    rm -Rf ./output/* *.model *.ppm *.txt classification_scheme
```

As you can see, I am new to Makefiles and I tried hard to improve this but I could not. I have a directory structure like this one:

```
+\
 |
 --texture: directory with sources to compile
 |
 --utility: directory with sources to compile
 |
 --svm: directory with sources to compile
 |
 --output: directory where the objects compiled are placed before they get together
 |
 --vlfeat: directory with headers
 |
 --main.c: source to compile
 |
 --Makefile
```

I want to compile the sources in each directory using one Makefile statement for each directory (now I have to compile each source file with a independent statement). And then I want to use another Makefile statement to compile together all the object files in "output" directory (now I have to compile the objects writing each one of them and there are many). I was trying to use the `wildcar` function but I could not manage to get work well.

And this is the output of `make clean all`:

```
rm -Rf ./output/* *.model *.ppm *.txt classification_scheme
g++ -Wall -O3 -I./vlfeat-0.9.21 -c ./texture/texture_pipelines.cpp -o ./output/texture_pipelines.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -I./vlfeat-0.9.21 -c ./utility/preprocess.c -o ./output/preprocess.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -I./vlfeat-0.9.21 -c -o ./output/main.o main.c
g++ -Wall -O3 -o ./output/svm.o -c ./svm/svm.cpp
g++ -Wall -O3 -I./vlfeat-0.9.21 -c -o ./output/trainpredict.o ./svm/trainpredict.c
g++ -Wall -O3 -c ./utility/general_utilities.c -o ./output/general_utilities.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -c ./utility/postprocess.c -o ./output/postprocess.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -c ./utility/load_data.c -o ./output/load_data.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -c ./utility/data_structures.c -o ./output/data_structures.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -c ./texture/slic.cpp -o ./output/slic.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -c ./texture/kmeans.cpp -o ./output/kmeans.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -c ./texture/vlad.cpp -o ./output/vlad.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -c ./texture/bow.cpp -o ./output/bow.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -I./vlfeat-0.9.21 -c ./texture/gmm.cpp -o ./output/gmm.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -I./vlfeat-0.9.21 -c ./texture/fishervectors.cpp -o ./output/fishervectors.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -I./vlfeat-0.9.21 -c ./texture/sift.cpp -o ./output/sift.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -I./vlfeat-0.9.21 -c ./texture/dsift.cpp -o ./output/dsift.o
g++ -Wall -O3 -o classification_scheme ./output/trainpredict.o ./output/texture_pipelines.o ./output/slic.o ./output/svm.o ./output/general_utilities.o \
./output/postprocess.o ./output/preprocess.o ./output/load_data.o ./output/data_structures.o ./output/kmeans.o ./output/vlad.o ./output/bow.o  ./output/gmm.o \
./output/fishervectors.o ./output/sift.o ./output/dsift.o ./output/main.o -lm -lopenblas -llapacke -lvl
```

Do you know how to rewrite this Makefile to compile this files using only 5 simple statements?

Comment: Please show the output of `make clean all`

Comment: Do you have to use a Makefile? Autotools is a more portable and maintainable build system, although it does have a slightly steeper learning curve.

Comment: Yes, is a requisite to use Makefile for compilation. @S.S.Anne

Comment: Autotools generates a Makefile. Would that work?

Comment: I wrote a [makefile demo](https://github.com/o11c/makefile-demo/) a while back if you want to look at it.

Comment: Conventions are good.  Conventionally, the C++ compiler is in `CXX`.  Flags for the c++ compiler are in `CXXFLAGS`.  Follow the conventions and you can simply delete most of your Makefile, as the default rules will do what you want.

Comment: Do people still use autotools?  It's been awhile since I came across a new piece of software that used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use the answer proposed by @MadScientist to create a Makefile that suits my needs. Here it is:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -O3
LDLIBS = -lm -lopenblas -llapacke -lvl
CPPFLAGS = -I./vlfeat-0.9.21

DIRS = texture utility svm .
OBJDIR = output

SRCS := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp,$(DIRS)))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))))

vpath %.cpp $(DIRS)




all: create_output_dir classification_scheme

classification_scheme: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

create_output_dir:
        mkdir -p ${OBJDIR}

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJDIR) *.model *.ppm *.txt classification_scheme




.PHONY: all clean
```

Thank you so much for all the help received.

Comment: Note that this won't work properly if you try to use parallel builds (`-j`).  Just putting the directory creation target before the program target in `all` doesn't mean one must be built before the other.  When make runs one command at a time, it happens to work out that way.  The only way to ensure one target is built first is by declaring a dependency relationship.

Comment: Also you should use `CXXFLAGS` not `CFLAGS` if compiling C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

IMO autotools is *way* overkill for this.

You can do this quite easily.  However there are some odd things about your makefile.

Most importantly, all your files are suffixed with a `.c` extension which means they are C files, but you are compiling them with `g++` which is a C++ compiler.  This does not make sense.  Either you should be naming your source files as C++ files, which means either `.cc` or `.cxx` or `.cpp` or similar, or you should be using a C compiler like `gcc` not `g++`.

I will assume your code is C code based on the file extensions.

Please use standard variables (`CC`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, `LDLIBS`):

```
CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = -I./vlfeat-0.9.21
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3
LDLIBS = -lopenblas -llapacke -lvl -lm

DIRS = texture utility svm
OBJDIR = output

SRCS := main.c $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c,$(DIRS)))
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(SRCS)))

vpath %.c $(DIRS)

all: classification_scheme

classification_scheme: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJDIR) *.model *.ppm *.txt classification_scheme

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: There are some `.cpp` files mixed in there.